# Contacted after interview for another phone call, but didn't get the call. Should I follow up again?

Tags: interviewing, follow-up

I interviewed for an internship job, and a week after the interview, I received an email from the interviewer that said he wanted to get on the phone and have another chat. I replied with all my available times, and he said he'll get back to me with some proposed times for the call.

But I haven't heard from him since. I emailed him a few days after his last email, asking him if he had decided on a time yet (I think I was pretty polite in that...), but still nothing.

It's almost two weeks, should I follow up again? I don't want to seem too nagging, but even if I'm no longer in consideration for the job, I'd like to know. I've got another offer that I need to reply to soon, but it's my second choice, and I'd really prefer this one. Should I include this in the follow up email too? I really don't want to sound threatening or impolite.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Do you have any other contact at the company? Maybe the person who interviewed you is on sick leave right now.

Comment: Yes, I would follow up.

Comment: @Llewellyn There was another recruiter that sent an email with the interview status (basically just that you're still in consideration, please wait) a couple weeks ago. Would it seem like going behind the interviewer's back if I ask this recruiter about it?

Answer (score 3):

There's really nothing to lose at this point, if it's been two weeks.  In my own job-hunting experience, it seems like the realistic potential for a callback drops off after one week.

Here's what I'd do, but it's a little risky.  I'd call the company and ask for the person.  That way you can make sure, you know, he still works there and everything, he isn't on vacation, etc.  Obviously, the e-mails are having little to no effect.

Then I'd tell him, I appreciate your continued consideration of me for this position, and I am still very interested.  Is it still available?  I think the conversation will flow pretty naturally from there.  If you leave a message and don't hear back within a week...  I think it's pretty unlikely you'll hear from them again.  I could be wrong, but I've learned the hard way not to wait for jobs that just don't come.  Also, it always rubs me the wrong way when people don't do what they say they're going to do.  You have a life and a future, and your time is just as valuable as anyone else's.

In the meantime, pursue the other opportunity.  Why not?  I know it's not your top choice, but even if you hear back from your #1 choice, it could be weeks till they reply with an offer or rejection.  #2 isn't too bad!  Better than #3, 4, or 5!  And if they're timely and on the ball, that's always a good thing.

From my experience, how a company runs in the interview and hiring process is often an indication of how well-oiled the machine is.  So #1 on the surface could end up running pretty rough inside.

Comment: "but it's a little risky" - why is it risky?

Comment: @Brandin It could be seen as very forward to call a company, especially since they said they would be the one to reach out; some companies (implicitly or explicitly) indicate not to call during the interview process. It could be seen as impatient, or even harassing, since the OP has reached out via e-mail twice and hasn't heard back.  So, it just depends on whether someone is willing to risk being seen as forward, impatient, and/or possibly harassing, as this could possibly damage future prospects with this company or recruiter.

Comment: while I agree it could be risky, but it could also show assertiveness. which is often desired by companies

Comment: Yeah I am thinking of just going with the other opportunity. I'm not sure if I should risk calling them for just an internship, because I might want to try applying to that company again after I graduate. Still, thanks for the advice! I think I should be a bit more aggressive and try contacting another recruiter.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is completely reasonable to reach out to the recruiter or hiring manager or last points of contact. Recruiting can sometimes fall behind, lose track of candidates, delete emails, etc. Sometimes delays are as simple as recruiting handed your file off to the hiring manager but he's busy with a program review and forgot to let recruiting know. Just be polite and don't be shocked if the answer is "Oh we didn't tell you? The position has been filled." But don't worry, you're not going to "scare them off" by being forward, so long as you're professional.

Comment: Thank you for the encouragement, I've tried contacting the recruiter again, don't know if he'll reply though.