# Follow-Up Interview Email

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I recently participated in a second round interview. I followed up with a Thank You email and was told the interviewer would get back to me to schedule a third round interview. The interviewer proposed a time but had to cancel due to schedule conflicts and said she would follow up with a new date/time. About a week has passed since the original time and date scheduled for a third round interview. Should I follow up again? Or wait to hear back?

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace Sara.  Your question is actually a pretty common one.  I hope you might find some helpful answers to these questions that have been asked in the past.

Comment: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10203/what-is-appropriate-email-follow-up-etiquette-after-no-response
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1538/how-soon-after-should-i-follow-up-on-a-missed-deadline
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/61540/sent-a-follow-up-email-and-i-received-a-reply-stating-that-she-would-contact-me
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/85536/contacted-after-interview-for-another-phone-call-but-didnt-get-the-call-shoul https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14040/how-long-do-i-wait-before-sending-a-follow-up-email

Comment: @Lumberjack good catch

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common situation. My recommendation would be to continue to look for work within your chosen market and "insure" your success with multiple applications / options / opportunities on your table.

You don't want to come across as desperate or needy. The situation may be just as you have described and they will get back to you shortly, or maybe you are being strung along as they investigate other more qualified applicants.

Either way continue to hope for the best whilst actively engaging other opportunities and planning for the worst. Best of luck. T